# How to find code file of a WordPress webpage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add something on a page of my WordPress site that is in localhost, but I can't find the file of that page in the htdocs folder from Xampp. I need the PHP file of that page to edit.

I searched in the "my site" folder in htdocs using some lines of code I can see when I inspect the source code of the page with SearchMyFiles.exe but nothing was found.

[image: database picture1]
[image: database picture2]
[image: database picture3]

Comment: WordPress is a CMS. Mostly, adding content should be done through its functionality, not by changing the code. Much of the actual page contents is stored in its database. Or you can write plugins, to enhance its capabilities. It depends what you're trying to alter. Read the user guide and documentation for more info.

Comment: I want to add a api to get info from another website. I want to add that in a specific page of site but I can't fine the php file

Comment: Have you tried installing Query Monitor and see if that helps?

Comment: No how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is probably stored in the **wp_posts** table of your database.

In the source code, you will only find files and scripts related to your Themes/template. For WordPress "pages", **the standard template used is usually the file "page.php"**.

Unless there is a more specific template file in your theme (e.g. archive.php to display archive pages), WordPress will use the template page.php to display all the pages of your site.

Basically, WordPress database stores your pages and posts by dividing all the items into 12 tables (n the database).

- wp_usermeta: saves metadata on your users
- wp_users: saves the user’s data on your site, including their password and username
- wp_termmeta: saves metadata on your taxonomy terms
- wp_term_relationships: stores the posts assignment to categories,
  saving the post and other types of contributions, also known as
  “terms.”
- wp_term_taxonomy: saves the taxonomy of wp_terms table’s term
- wp_terms: saves all your site’s taxonomy terms, such as the tags and
  categories
- wp_commentmeta: saves all the metadata of your site’s comments
- wp_comments: saves all your posts’ comments, which includes the time
  and the poster’s name
- wp_postmeta: stores all the metadata from the wp_posts, like the
  custom fields and editing lock
- **wp_posts**: stores every file or content of your website, including the
  title, text content, modification date, creation date,author,and the publishing status excerpt.

Comment: I did not find those tables.

Comment: Hello. may you show me the list of tables you have?

Comment: I don't know how to show you

Comment: @ADyson
you know I want the directory of the php file of a page

Comment: Basically (depending on your config). You could probably access your database from the URL: http://localhost/phpmyadmin, or from the commandline directly doing 'mysql' command. So take a picture (screen capture) of what you see, and update your question uploading the resulting picture.

Comment: you can see the pictures

Answer (score 1):

Many of the pages in a WordPress website are not based on files unlike HTML sites. Are you sure that this page is based on a file or is it based on some database values? If you are unsure, then feel free to provide the URL.

Comment: if there is not a file, how can I make a php file for a page?

Comment: with a page template in simple cases, but it depends on what kind of page you are trying to make a template for.  Is this a "page" from the wp admin?

Comment: in a online shop website, for the payment part is need some data for example neme, family and etc and I want to use a api to get the userdata from another website, and I should write the code on the payment file code

Comment: A WooCommerce shop? There are a lot of great WooCommerce plugins, I’d start searching for one of those

Comment: yes that, you are searching for what?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a Template Hierarchy.
Here is the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

E.x. For homepage, WordPress looks for home.php first. If the file is absent then it goes to index.php

Similarly:
Front Page display:

1. front-page.php
2. home.php
3. page.php
4. index.php (if none of the above 3 files are present, then WordPress follow index.php)

For Single Post:

1. single-{post-type}-{slug}.php
2. single-{post-type}.php
3. single.php
4. singular.php
5. index.php

For Single Page:

1. custom template file
2. page-{slug}.php
3. page-{id}.php
4. page.php
5. singular.php
6. index.php

To find whether you are on post or page, just check the admin top bar (if you are logged in). You will find edit post or edit page button at the admin top bar.